# Delete all values in list outside of specified range python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list (let's call it L1) with plenty of decimal values. How do I remove all values outside of some specified range while keeping all values within the range?
For instance, let's say I define my range as [-1, 1] and

```
L1 = [-2, 0.1, 0.75, 4]
```

I would want my output to be a new list, i.e.

```
L2 = [0.1, 0.75]
```

I've heard there was a way to do this with numpy (though I can't find the SO question for the life of me), but I was wondering if there was another way, just using the built-in functions (of course if numpy is better for this sort of thing, then that's fine too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use list comprehension:

```
L2 = [ x for x in L1 if -1 <= x <= 1 ]
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do it using [boolean indexing with NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). For large lists/arrays this can be much faster than a list comprehension or `filter` approach:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L1 = [-2, 0.1, 0.75, 4] 
>>> A1 = np.array(L1)           # convert it to an array
>>> A1[(A1 >= -1) & (A1 <= 1)]  # remove all values that are not in the range [-1, 1]
array([ 0.1 ,  0.75])
```

Comment: The right answer.  List comprehensions will be much slower

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the perfect job for `filter`. (only in python 2!)

```
L1 = [-2, 0.1, 0.75, 4]
filtered_L1 = list(filter(lambda x: -1. <= x <= 1., L1))
print(filtered_L1)
# [0.1, 0.75]
```

Python 3 you are better off with a list comprehension;

```
L1 = [-2, 0.1, 0.75, 4]
L1 = [x for x in L1 if -1. <= x <= 1.]
print(L1)
# [0.1, 0.75]
```

Comment: Not in Python3 (see @BrightOne's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45038498/2897372)).

Comment: Wow thanks @Błotosmętek, didn't know that. Python 2.7 virtualenv got me again :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`.

```
L2 = list(filter(lambda x: -1 <= x <= 1, L1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another.

```
L2 = [ii for ii in L1 if (ii <= 1 and ii >= -1)]
```